# Enhance performance of algorithm by reducing it's complexity or optimizing .NET Core tools

Tags: performance, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, query-optimization, nested-loops

I have a list of `Outcomes` which I'm loading onto memory; this list has a property called `OutcomeConditions` which is another list of conditions for each of the outcomes. I also have a list `Rules` of arbitrary rules that I'm loading onto memory from a data source.
My algorithm filters only the outcomes whose conditions match at least one rule in the `Rules` list.

The algorithm, which is implemented in .NET Core using C# is functional, but it is compute-intensive and thus slow. The number of outcomes is always has a cap of 60 (call this n), the number of rules has a cap of 12 (say m) and for outcome conditions it's 3 (call this p) at most; hence complexity totals O(n*m*p).

Some context regarding the significance: this algorithm is implemented in a Web API endpoint which is quite mission critical as it is called frequently and largely affects the user experience.

I am using EF Core as my ORM and I have tried the following in improving the overall performance of this API endpoint and underlying services:

- Implemented repository pattern for data access layer, accessing all data as `IQueryable<T>`
- made use of `.AsNoTracking()` for readonly data from the db, to reduce unnecessary tracking overhead
- Used bulk inserts wherever possible on the repository layer to improve performance,
- Implemented all data access and business logic as asynchronous processing
- Implemented `for` instead of `foreach` or `LINQ` iterations to reduce overhead (since iterating over an array is supposedly quicker than on a list)

This improvement approach was targeting the mechanical sympathy of the tooling used and wasn't satisfactory, since I feel that the underlying algorithm can be improved.

Here is some some code, particularly with the iterations, starting with the outer loop:

```
for (int outcomeIndex = 0; outcomeIndex < inputOdds.Length-1; outcomeIndex++)
{
     var savedOutcome = await oddService.GetOutcomeByOutcomeId(inputOdds[outcomeIndex].OutcomeId);
     var filteredOutcome = await conditionService.FilterOutcomeConditions(savedOutcome, umbracoGame,language, IsFilterActive);

     if (filteredOutcome != null && !IsDuplicateOutcome(filteredOutcome, filteredOdds))
         filteredOdds.Add(await CustomizeUmbracoOutcome(filteredOutcome));
}
```

The outer loop iterates over each outcome and calls `FilterOutcomeConditions` method, part of which is shown below (and contains a nested loop for validating each outcome condition against the list of rules):

```
foreach (var rule in umbracoGame.OutcomeRules)
            {
                var validConditions = new List<OutcomeCondition>();
                if (filterActive && !rule.IsActive)
                    continue;
                foreach (var condition in outcomeConditions)
                    ValidateIfConditionMeetsCurrentUmbracoRule(rule, validConditions, condition);

                int numberOfRules = await GetNumberOfUmbracoRulesForOutcome(rule);
                if (validConditions.Count > 0 && outcomeConditions.Count() == numberOfRules)
                    if (doConditionsMeetUmbracoRequirements(validConditions, rule))
                    {
                        filteredOutcome.Conditions = validConditions.Select(x=>mapper.Map<OutcomeCondition, OutcomeConditionDto>(x));
                        filteredOutcome.Summary = rule.Summary;
                        filteredOutcome.Title = rule.Title;
                        filteredOutcome.Thumbnail = rule.Thumbnail;
                        return filteredOutcome;
                    }
            }
            return null;
```

I would like to know if there is a way to optimize the core algorithm which is currently O(n*m*p) in time and space. Alternatively any performance enhancement from the tooling (.NET Core, EF Core etc) that I might have overlooked (or interpreted incorrectly) would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a stored procedure?

Comment: You shouldn't get data record-by-record in loops. Get all required data in advance, then you can use PLINQ to do parallel calculations in memory. Also, use EFC 6.0 at least if you don't already do that.

Comment: Update: I got significant improvements by removing database calls in the loop(s) as @Gert suggests, instead I made use of the data already in memory and used concurrent execution of Task.WhenAll() for async calls that are independent.